# Problems installing hardhat using npm and node

Tags: nodejs

I really need to be able to use hardhat on vscode and I am having so many problems trying to use node and npm. Does anyone know how to solve these errors? I know node and npm are installed because I ran node -v and npm -v. I already tried deleting and reinstalling node and npm.

[image: npm errors]

Comment: Node-gyp require extra configuration steps on Windows. Check their documentation https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows. Another alternative is to hardhat from WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

Its saying operation not permiited try using `sudo` . If the problem still persists try to downgrade your npm and node .